# How to create a hack proof unique code

Tags: algorithm

I am creating bunch of unique codes in order to run a promotional campaign.
The campaign will run for a total of 20 million unique items. The validity of the code will be one year. I am currently looking for best possible option.
I can use only 0-9 and A-Z in the code. so that limits me to using 36 unique  characters in my code. The end user will need to key in the unique cd in the system and get offers. The unique code will not be tied against any user or transaction to begin with.

One way to generate unique code is create incremental numbers and then convert them to base36 to get a unique cd. The problem with this is that its easily hackable. Users can start inserting unqiue cd in incremental fashion and redeem offers not meant for them. I am thinking of introducing some kind of randomisation. Need suggestions regarding the same.

Note - The limit of max characters in the code is 8.

Comment: Use a hashing function to generate unique codes from sequential inputs.  I use `crc32` extensively in my own work, but there are many other functions which may serve better for you.  To make it unhackable, use multiple hashing functions, or a secret salt.

Comment: nothing is hack proof.

Comment: "I can use only 0-9 and A-Z in the code." People will complain that their code `OI6` wasn't accepted, when it actually was `01G`. Your character set is really smaller than 36 values.

Comment: This is not a good design. You simply must tie codes to particular users at the time the code is issued, and when redeemed, you must make the user provide a password or PIN.

Comment: Also: "The limit of max characters in the code is 8" `int(36**8 / 20e6) == 141055`, so even if you have 36 distinct characters, there is a one in ~141055 chance that a random code is valid. If someone tries 10000 random codes per day for a year, you can expect that they'll win about 258 items. It's probably more important to implement rate limiting and fraud detection if you're going to let people redeem those codes online.

Comment: Is "cd" the same as "code"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a cryptographically strong random number generator to generate 40-bit numbers (i.e. sequences of 5-byte random arrays). Converting each array to base-36 will yield a sequence of random eight-character codes. Run an additional check on each code to make sure that there are no duplicates. Using a hash set on the converted strings will let you perform this task in a reasonable time.

Here is an example implementation in Java:

```
Set<String> codes = new HashSet<>();
SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
byte[] data = new byte[5];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 100000 ; i++) {
    rng.nextBytes(data);
    long val = ((long)(data[0] & 0xFF))
    | (((long)(data[1] & 0xFF)) << 8)
    | (((long)(data[2] & 0xFF)) << 16)
    | (((long)(data[3] & 0xFF)) << 24)
    | (((long)(data[4] & 0xFF)) << 32);
    String s = Long.toString(val, 36);
    codes.add(s);
}
System.out.println("Generated "+codes.size()+" codes.");
```

[Demo.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcmwtTFZOU3c1cDA)

Comment: This is a waste of a CSPRNG, though, because this program is biased towards lower-valued codes. To do this correctly, you'll have to either generate 11 random numbers in varying ranges (`popcount(36**8) == 11`) and add them, or use some clever number theoretical trick to obfuscate the bias. Also, I'm not entirely sure if OP is okay with the codes it generates that are shorter than 8 characters.

Comment: @Rhymoid The limit of roughly 40 bits makes it hard to stay hacker-safe without additional checks for fraudulent activity, such as rejecting IP addresses of people who make multiple failed attempts to redeem the code, using and artificially increasing the time that it takes to perform a check. I think this approach is good enough to generate codes, though, in a sense that having access to a few of these codes wouldn't give away their generation strategy

Answer (score 0):

Use a Guid (C# code):

```cs
string code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0,8).ToUpperInvariant();
```

Since we have a hexadecimal representation we get digits and the characters `a` to `f`. We get 16^8 possible codes which is > 4 billion codes. One every 214 for 20 million codes.

`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` yields a string like `"6b984c2f-5866-4745-ac34-d5088a56070f"`. Since the first group has a length of 8 characters we can just take the first 8 chars and convert them to upper case. The result looks like `"6B984C2F"`.

Note that this can yield duplicate codes. We can avoid this like this:

```cs
var codes = new HashSet<string>();
while (codes.Count < 20000000) {
    string code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0,8).ToUpperInvariant();
    codes.Add(code);
}
```

The HashSet allows you to add an item more than once but always only keeps one of them. (Just as math sets.)

---

If you want to use the full range of possible values the one-liner from above does not do it. With the whole alphabet plus digits we get 36^8 =  ~2.8 * 10^12 possible codes. One every 141,055 for 20 million codes. That's better but still not completely hack proof. You will need to limit the number of entry attempts, use a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) etc.

```cs
const string Base = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const int CodeLength = 8;
const int NumCodes = 20000000;

var random = new Random();
var codes = new HashSet<string>();
var chars = new char[CodeLength];
while (codes.Count < NumCodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CodeLength; i++) {
        int pos = random.Next(Base.Length);
        chars[i] = Base[pos];
    }
    string code = new string(chars);
    codes.Add(code);
}
```

Comment: That limits you to `16**8` unique values, so one in every `214 == int(16**8 / 20e6)` random codes is valid. This is not at all hack proof. If you try one random code every day, there's an 82% chance that you'll have won at least one thing by the end of the year.

Comment: I added a solution making use of the full range of possibles values; however, it is not as elegant as the one-liner from above.

Comment: The question was about a "hack proof unique code", so as elegent the abuse of the GUID library may be, it's not relevant to the question. By the way, this is an X/Y problem (it can't be solved with the reward count and code length constraints), and any "hack proof" solution will require an answer that is "too broad".